# Does elasticsearch support SQL like OR conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

For example in SQL I would write `(a AND b) OR (c AND d)`.  But I can't find a direct analogue in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable via [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "foo"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "bar"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "baz"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "fox"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch,
`should` is equivalent to OR in SQL and `must` is equivalent to AND.
So the following query is equivalent to your SQL query and will fetch first 10 results.

`(A=a AND B=b) OR (C=c AND D=d)`

```
GET /<indexName>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "A": "a"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "B": "b"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "C": "c"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "D": "d"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html